# error with the a magento onepage checkout CSS

Tags: css, magento, checkout

hi i have a problem with a magento onepage checkout plugin its making the blocks split and its not giving a nice clean look . 
there are 3 blocks that need to be next to each other can some one help me find the error. i tryed using firbug but i cannot seem to get it right.

the page that needs to be fixed : 
http://www.beaniecaps.nl/index.php/onepagecheckout/

please notice that u need to make a account to see the checkout page .

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for this in `skin/frontend/base/default/css/onepagecheckout.css`
`#onepagecheckout_orderform .col3-set .col-2, #onepagecheckout_orderform .col3-set .col-1`
and add `float:left` to it.

Comment: #onepagecheckout_orderform .col3-set .col-1{width:27%;margin:0;}
#onepagecheckout_orderform .col3-set .col-2{width:33%;margin-left:4%;margin-right:0;}
#onepagecheckout_orderform .col3-set .col-3{float:right;}

#onepagecheckout_orderform #register-customer-password{margin-bottom:5px;}
#onepagecheckout_orderform #ship_address_block{margin-top:35px;}


where should i add it ?

Answer (score 1):

add float:left to this class

```
#onepagecheckout_orderform .col3-set .col-2, #onepagecheckout_orderform .col3-set .col-1
```

also remove width:auto from this element

```
<div class="grid_12 col-main" style="/* width: auto; */">
```

This will ensure you use full width of the page.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem here but after talking with IWD support it was just necessary to edit the  onepagecheckout.css and add to the end this

```
.grid12-12, .grid-full {
width: 100% !important;
}
```

hope this work for you

Cheers